# How to navigate back to a Page and avoid reloading webview?

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone Store app (XAML) with a Page (MainPage.xaml) that has a webview that loads content and URLs. At certain point i have to navigate to a different windows phone page (Page2.xaml), once the data there is submitted i navigate back to MainPage.xaml, but the webview control always reloads the content and user has to reenter the data again.

Is there any way to make a snapshot of the webview and load it when Navigating back to MainPage.xaml?

I have tried the NavigationHelper, but in the onNavigatingFrom event from MainPage when i try to save the Frame.Content, its the Page2 the one being passed in the NavigationEventArgs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to never leave the page. To do this, create two grids. One for the webview and one for the other view. When the page loads, show the first grid and hide the second grid. When you want to show the second view hide the first grid and show the second.

I have used this method in several apps on the phone and windows store and you can simulate popups this way as well.

Comment: That sir, is a nice idea, And some nice effects could come into play to make it elegant. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Is this the only way even now? The suggested approach makes sense for trivial webview content with small number of pages. But if the xaml pages are generic and webview content differs for each instance of the page, then maintaining a chain of such pages like a -> b -> c -> d and so on would become complex.